# CSS highlight links with custom border

Tags: html, css, styling

I need a little help with my problem. I get following effect with this code:

```
#navLink{
font-family: oduda_bold;
font-size: 17px;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
}
#navLink:focus{
border-radius: 10px;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 0px;
background-color: #ef5e99;
}
```

[WRONG HIGHLIGHT](http://s17.postimg.org/e4t0h6tij/foonone.png?noCache=1423758171)

and I would like to have it highlighted like this:

[NICE HIGHLIGHT](http://s27.postimg.org/q436pj70v/foook.png?noCache=1423758192)

Is that possible to highlight link with larger (than its textvalue) area ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Add padding and then fiddle around with the border radius until it meets your expectations:

```
#navLink:focus{
  padding: 10px /*here*/
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

Comment: So simple ! I have no idea why I didn't use padding attribute here. Thank You !

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use padding and set your link into an inline-block.

```
#navLink{
  display:inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
```